# Batch HQL Insert

Tags: c#, java, .net, hibernate, nhibernate

Anyway to do this?

```
var hql = "insert into Entites.SapDetail (column1, column2) VALUES ('200', '131758'), ('200', '131758')";

session.CreateQuery(hql).ExecuteUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an SQL query to accomplish the insert:

```
session.createSqlQuery (sql).executeUpdate ();
```

Also check out the `addEntity()` method of `SQLQuery` if you wish to use entities in your query.

Comment: Ohhh really? So i dont need to execute an hql? Can I insert directly to the table, instead of the object? like: insert into table (a,b) values (1,2) ???

Comment: Yes, sir.  You can give the `createSqlQuery()` method a `String` containing purely SQL.  (BTW, don't forget to accept the answer ... if it does, in fact, satisfy your question.)